# Get member variable content in MFC class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have dialog that has Edit Text control that is connected to m_edit variable wit Class Wizard.

I have application  that uses this dialog:

```
BOOL CPreparationApp::InitInstance(){
    MyDlg Dlg;

    m_pMainWnd = &Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();

    Dlg.m_edit. //how to get string content fromthis m_edit?

    return TRUE;
}
```

How to get string content fromthis m_edit?

Comment: Class Wizard can make either CString or CEdit variables for an edit control. What is the type of m_edit? If it is CString you should already have what you want with Dlg.m_edit.

Comment: Variable type is CEdit

Comment: You can use GetWindowText(); function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get entered info from modal MFC form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813459/get-entered-info-from-modal-mfc-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After DoModal has returned the edit control no longer exists. You can use m_edit.GetWindowText in the dialog's OnOK function to save the data into a CString dialog member variable. The CString member variable can be used after DoModal has returned.